# Magento 2 Errors

Tags: php, magento, magento2

Yesterday I have tried to install Magento 2. When trying to access the front end I got plenty of errors both on the front end of the site and the Magento 2 admin. Since this is my first time I am not quite sure what are those errors and how to resolve them. Can you please help?

**Storefront:**

```
1 exception(s): 
Exception #0 (UnexpectedValueException): Setup version for module 'MSP_AdminRestriction' is not specified

Exception #0 (UnexpectedValueException): Setup version for module 'MSP_AdminRestriction' is not specified #0 /home/ar26/projects/fv/html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/DbVersionInfo.php(56):
Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->isModuleVersionEqual('MSP_AdminRestri...', '0.1.3') 
#1 /home/ar26/projects/fv/html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/DbVersionInfo.php(79):
Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->isSchemaUpToDate('MSP_AdminRestri...') 
#2 /home/ar26/projects/fv/html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(55):
Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->getDbVersionErrors() 
#3 /home/ar26/projects/fv/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67):
Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 
#4 /home/ar26/projects/fv/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63):
Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
Array, 'front-controlle...') 
#5 /home/ar26/projects/fv/html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55):
Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 /home/ar26/projects/fv/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 
#7 /home/ar26/projects/fv/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
Array, 'front-controlle...') 
#8 /home/ar26/projects/fv/html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73):
Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /home/ar26/projects/fv/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 
#10 /home/ar26/projects/fv/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26):
Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array) 
#11 /home/ar26/projects/fv/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135):
Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 
#12 /home/ar26/projects/fv/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258):
Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() 
#13 /home/ar26/projects/fv/html/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
```

**Magento Admin:**

```
1 exception(s): Exception 
#0 (UnexpectedValueException): Setup version for module 'MSP_AdminRestriction' is not specified
Exception #0 (UnexpectedValueException): Setup version for module 'MSP_AdminRestriction' is not specified 
#0 /home/ar26/projects/fv/html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/DbVersionInfo.php(56):
Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->isModuleVersionEqual('MSP_AdminRestri...', '0.1.3') 
#1 /home/ar26/projects/fv/html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/DbVersionInfo.php(79):
Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->isSchemaUpToDate('MSP_AdminRestri...') 
#2 /home/ar26/projects/fv/html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(55):
Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->getDbVersionErrors() 
#3 /home/ar26/projects/fv/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142):
Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 
#4 /home/ar26/projects/fv/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26):
Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array) 
#5 /home/ar26/projects/fv/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135):
Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http)) 
#6 /home/ar26/projects/fv/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258):
Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() 
#7 /home/ar26/projects/fv/html/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#8 {main}
```

Answer (score 3):

Open your **database** for this **Magento** and search the table

> setup_module

In this table remove the follwoig module ***MSP_AdminRestriction*** and   after that run the following commands.

> php bin/magetno setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magetno setup:static-content:deploy -f

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a registration.php file to register your module.

In app/code/MSP/AdminRestriction/registration.php.

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'MSP_AdminRestriction',
    __DIR__
);
```

And fire below commond

```
 php bin/magento module:enable MSP_AdminRestriction
 php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

We have 3 ways to resolve this issue.

1. You can disable the module by command

   php bin/magento module:disable Module_Name

   php bin/magento setup:upgrade

   php bin/magento setup:di:compile
2. you can edit app/etc/config.xml file and find your module by name and change status.

   example:- 'Namespace_Modulename => 0,
3. Open Database and find "setup_module" table and remove your module entry
   Then you need to run below command

   php bin/magento module:disable Module_Name

   php bin/magento setup:upgrade

   php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have already added `/app/code/Namespace/Module/registration.php` and `/app/code/Namespace/Module/composer.json` files in your module folder.

So in your case, may be the file/folder permission is an error that could be resolved by changing the permission of the module folder

```
chmod 775 <module path> -R
```

Finally, run these commands to enable your module and upgrade setup (don't forget to replace `Module_Name` with your module)

```
php -f bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Module_Name
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

**Another Solution**

You can also specify your module name directly into `app/etc/config.php`, if `MSP_AdminRestriction` is not specified in `config.php` then by adding below line

```
'MSP_AdminRestriction' => 1,
```

and run the command

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please execute this command one by one,

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

If Magento version > 2.2
`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

If Magento version < 2.2
`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Answer (score 0):

Find in your m2 database, table "setup_module", delete record where module = 'MSP_AdminRestriction'
Then, run:
php bin/magetno setup:upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you miss some files of this module.

Copy them from git https://github.com/magespecialist/m2-MSP_AdminRestriction?files=1

And run

```
bin/magento module:enable m2-MSP_AdminRestriction


bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

And if it's not in developing mode run also

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you have a fail attempt with same root directory name.
You can try it with different root directory name or flush browser cache and retry.

I was facing similar problem and it was resolved by following above steps.

Answer (score 0):

Check the setup_version node in the file module.xml of MSP_AdminRestriction Extension, whether its define correctly or not.

Here is an example of the module.xml file for the extension Flat_Toy

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">`
    <module name="Flat_Toy" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

After verifying it run the commands :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to setup_module in DB, find MSP_AdminRestriction in records. either set version or just remove the record.
then run php bin/magento setup:upgrade